Relating to the Mishkan and Kodshim
Despite being the topic of almost 40 percent of the written Torah, roughly 30 percent of Mishnah, and a major theme in daily liturgy, the Mishkan/Mikdash, and related laws of Kodshim and Taharos are mostly very distant from common practice and thoughts.
What are some resources, approaches, frameworks or ideas that help you as modern person find meaning in this Chelek of Torah?
(Perhaps including Taharos here seems unrelated, but many of the halachot of Taharos are related to entering the Mikdash and eating Kodshim, and Rambam argues that many laws of Tumah are motivated by Kodshim)

The contemplation of kodesh and chol ...Rav Soloveitchik on this topic is very eye opening

@sam thanks for sharing! Can you provide a source in his writings I can look at?

The Mishkan is very connected to the notion of Hashem desiring a dwelling in the lowest world, which is heavily discussed in Chassidus. You will find a lot on the Mishkan, drawing very relevant, deep answers that will open up this whole topic, in many maamarim and sichot.
